# hdfs copy folder to network file system ends up in error

Tags: hdfs

One of my clients is used to save to a NFS volume the contents of some HDFS folders. Sometimes during the copy I'll receive the following error

```
copying /folder/foo
copyToLocal: Input/output error
```

I thought that some of the files inside the foo folder might be corrupt, but a check with hdfs fsck didn't report anything strange. In the foo folder there are many many files so it's not feasible to manually search for something strange. I tried to enable debug mode for the copyToLocal command but there is no clue about any type of error. How could I debug this issue ?

I have the gut feeling that there are some networking issues on the NFS, but I also don't know how to debug this kind of problems.

The HDFS folders are also very large, I don't know if this could cause any additional problem.

We are in a Kerberos environment and we're executing commands after the kinit as the hdfs superuser.

p.s. Probably SO isn't the right place to ask this question, feel free to redirect me to the right website :)

Comment: check whether user has sufficient permission on NFS to create files/directories.

Comment: Hi, what do you mean ? I think that in the case of a permission problem I would not be able to write anything at all to the NFS. Instead I'm  experiencing this error only on certain folders. Also (i'll add this to the question since this may be relevant) I forgot to mention that I'm in a kerberized environment and I'm launching the commands as the hdfs superuser

Comment: what if source location on NFS is newly added (say parent folder of subdirectory you are trying to write) and you are not aware of it, in this case your HDFS user doesn't have sufficient permission to this newly created NFS then also you will encounter same error.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late response but I recently switched projects and didn't have the time to further investigate the issue (actually I totally forgot about it). What do you mean with this ? What do you mean when you say that the HDFS user does not have sufficient permission on a newly created NFS ? The NFS is not newly created and the user has the right permissions to write to the folder since it is able to write some folders but it eventually fails on other directories.